# Navigate user to either login or other page upon app load using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to create a Single Page Application (mobile app). The code below allowed me to successfully inject the home page with a login module upon click off a button:

```
$("#loginButton").click(function() {
  location.href='#login';
});
```

However, I later decided to automatically navigate the user to a login page if a login was not detected, and a navigation page if it was detected. When I switched to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  location.href='#login';
});
```

I received the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
    at Object.LocationHashbangUrl.$$parse (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js:8708:40)

I was wondering why I received this error, and what is the appropriate way to send a user to either 1 of 2 pages upon loading of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Angular" way would be to use [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location), like this:

```
$location.path('login');
```

Your error seems to be coming by using Angular's location service (not the native JS one, did you alias the Angular one?) with the syntax of the JS one.

Comment: I put $location.path('login'); in the controller. I no longer get the error when testing localhost, but the error still appears when I run it on my Android device.

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version on the Android? Because the device shouldn't matter.

Comment: I was using jQuery Mobile, which from what I just read could conflict with AngularJS. I removed the jQuery Mobile include, built and ran the app on my Android Device, and the appropriate login page loaded without error.